# DOM дерево и плагины для Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, chrome-extension

Добрый день, написал плагин для хром, вроде доступ из под него к DOM дереву страницы есть. ALERT с помощью jQuery появляется, но никак не могу, сменить стиль на блочный, подскажите что я делаю не так:

**Манифест:**

```
{
"name":" ПОИСК 1.1 ",
"description":"ПОИСК ",
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"1",
"permissions":["tabs","<all_urls>"],
"browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},
 "web_accessible_resources": ["LeoScript.js"] ,
 "permissions":["tabs","<all_urls>"]
}
```

**Попап:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text"  placeholder="найти">
    <button  type="submit" id="find" value="поиск"> НАЙТИ </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#find").click(function(){
    $('.ng-hide').css('display', 'block!Important');
  });
});
```

**Фоновый обработчик:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript( {"file": "LeoScript.js"});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя назначать `!important` таким способом.

Вместо `$('.ng-hide').css('display', 'block!Important')` можно использовать это:

```
$('.ng-hide').each(function () {
  this.style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');
});
```

Или можно перезаписать весь аттрибут style:

```
$('.ng-hide').css('cssText', 'display: block !important');
```

Comment: спасибо, но что-то не работатет, так-же тестирую алертов вывод:
если просто "голый" алерт, то срабатывает как надо:

 alert("111");

если в обработке при клике на кнопку то, почему-то не срабатывает

$("#find").click(function(){


 alert("111");

});